# Separate Strings from one Columns IN SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I just need to separate from this kind of line in my database

```
   V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;;
```

Like this

```
Status      UPD
datefrom    17/04/2012 00:00:00
dateto      18/04/2012 00:00:00
arrivAL     LGW
Departure   LOH
Code        VAC
Rank        CP
SpecF       X1
Extra       OL
```

I don't know how can i paste in Horizontal thats y i paste in Vertical please help

Im using this Funcation in Oracle for statu and rest

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( EA.ACTIVITYINFO, '([^;]*)(;|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1 )
```

Comment: Have you considered saving it to a file and then re-importing the data?

Comment: Software saving data like this .. i just need output to create reports

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for your favorite ETL or importing tool, each of which has steps to process, distill, and convert to what you want.

Comment: how can i do this in ETL

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will split the field and return a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnParseList
(
    @Delimiter CHAR,
    @Text TEXT
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (RowID SMALLINT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Data VARCHAR(8000))
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextPos INT,
        @LastPos INT

    SELECT  @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, 1),
        @LastPos = 0

    WHILE @NextPos > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT  @Result
                (
                    Data
                )
            SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, @NextPos - @LastPos - 1)

            SELECT  @LastPos = @NextPos,
                @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, @NextPos + 1)
        END

    IF @NextPos <= @LastPos
        INSERT  @Result
            (
                Data
            )
        SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos)

    RETURN
END
```

Here is the [original Source](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=76033) of this code

A less efficient way to achieve this would be to use `while` and `substring` functions.

```
Declare @Delimiter Char(1)= ';'; 
Declare @Text NVarchar(Max)= 'V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;;';
Declare @RowsToCount Int
  , @CurrentRow Int = 1;
Declare @FieldsToCount Int
  , @CurrentField Int
  , @PreviousField Int
  , @FieldID Int;


Create Table [#Test]
    (
      [Tid] Int Identity(1 , 1)
    , [TextToCheck] NVarchar(Max)
    );

Create Table [#Test2]
    (
      [Tid] Int
    , [FieldID] Int
    , [FieldStart] Int
    , [FieldEnd] Int
    , [TextOutput] NVarchar(Max)
    );

Insert  [#Test]
        ( [TextToCheck] )
        Select  @Text;

Select  @RowsToCount = Max([T].[Tid])
From    [#Test] [T];

While @CurrentRow <= @RowsToCount
    Begin
        Select  @CurrentField = 0;

        Select  @FieldsToCount = Len([T].[TextToCheck])
                - Len(Replace([T].[TextToCheck] , @Delimiter , ''))
        From    [#Test] [T]
        Where   [T].[Tid] = @CurrentRow;

        Select  @FieldID = 1;

        While @FieldID <= @FieldsToCount
            Begin
                Select  @PreviousField = @CurrentField;

                Select  @CurrentField = CharIndex(@Delimiter ,
                                                  [T].[TextToCheck] ,
                                                  @PreviousField + 1)
                From    [#Test] [T]
                Where   [T].[Tid] = @CurrentRow;

                Insert  [#Test2]
                        ( [Tid]
                        , [FieldID]
                        , [TextOutput]
                        , [FieldStart]
                        , [FieldEnd]
                        )
                        Select  [T].[Tid]
                              , @FieldID
                              , Replace(Substring([T].[TextToCheck] ,
                                                  @PreviousField ,
                                                  @CurrentField
                                                  - @PreviousField) , ';' , '')
                              , @PreviousField
                              , @CurrentField
                        From    [#Test] [T]
                        Where   [T].[Tid] = @CurrentRow;


                Select  @FieldID = @FieldID + 1;
                Print @PreviousField;
                Print @CurrentField;
            End;

        Select  @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1;    
    End;

Select  [T].[Tid]
      , [T].[TextToCheck]
      , [T2].[FieldID]
      , [T2].[TextOutput]
From    [#Test] [T]
        Left Join [#Test2] [T2]
            On [T2].[Tid] = [T].[Tid];

Drop Table [#Test];
Drop Table [#Test2];
```

To use this in your example, you would insert your raw data into the test table.

The results looks like this

```
Tid |TextToCheck                                                                |FieldID    |TextOutput
1   |V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;; |1          |V1
1   |V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;; |2          |UPD
1   |V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;; |11         |201204170000
1   |V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;; |12         |201204180000
1   |V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;; |13         |LGW
1   |V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;; |14         |LOH
1   |V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;; |15         |VAC
1   |V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;; |16         |CP
```

Comment: is there any other way i dont want to create funcation

Comment: @FaisalKhan you can take the code out of the function and apply it to your data directly, but that's a lot of work when the code is right there ^ - you can create the function on a separate reporting database and then call it so it's not in your source db if that's your concern about creating functions

Comment: My Admin didnt aloow me to create a funcation

Comment: @FaisalKhan do you have a local install to develop on? You can then show the code is functional and then have your admin create the function

Comment: yes ... but you now IT department how they work for this funcation i have to wait around 1 month so no chance

Comment: @FaisalKhan if it's urgent, you can create a linked server on your desktop version to live, call the data and then apply the function locally - no waiting for IT!

Comment: How can i do that ??

Comment: @FaisalKhan something like this USE master;  
GO  
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   N'SEATTLESales',  
   N'SQL Server';  
GO  

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Id int,Value Varchar(200))
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Id int ,Value Varchar(200))
INSERT INTO @TABLE
(Id,[Value])
VALUES
(1,' V1;UPD;;;;;;;;;201204170000;201204180000;LGW;LOH;VAC;CP;;;;;;;X1;OL;;;;;;;')

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT A.ID,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Value FROM  
(SELECT ID,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Value, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Value FROM @Table A) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Value.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)

DELETE FROM @Temp WHERE [Value] =''
SELECT * FROM @Temp t
```